# oracle apex ajax flow issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i am getting an error on my home page when i log in to my oracle ords application. My home page has a couple of charts that's refreshing every 10 seconds however when i log into that page one or more of the charts will not show data and to the top of the page will say error.

the only temporary solution will be to refresh apache tomcat. but as i say its temporary. Below is the error am see when i check the logs in chrome.

[image]

desktop_all.min.js?v=18.1.0.00.45:4 POST http://192.168.*.*/ords/wwv_flow.ajax 400

Comment: How long after you log into the application do you get the error? Go to the Shared Components > Security Attributes. What values do you have for Maximum Session Length in Seconds AND Maximum Session Idle Time in Seconds?

Comment: i dont have anything for Maximum and minimum sessions

Comment: In that case, you'd be using the defaults, which should be fine for most folks. I just wanted to make sure someone didn't put a value in either that was too low. How are you refreshing the regions? Try doing this, set the Server-side Condition for all but one of the regions to Never and test. Then, one by one, clear the condition for various regions and test. Try to identify whether one region is causing the issue.

Comment: i am using the automatic refresh in the region attribute settings, i did the trial and error and it worked but on different occasions it worked for a different regions. By this is mean-  i created a duplicate page and i started deleting regions so lets say when i deleted region 4 the error stopped. i will create a duplicate page again and delete region 4 and the error will still be there , and then i will delete more regions and lets say i reach region 7 and the error will stop. So its no specific region

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the error your seeing in the browser logs? How many regions are refreshing? The "192" address indicates you're running this locally, is that right?

Comment: i have edited the post and added the image, i have about 12 different regions and yes its local.

Comment: Interesting. This would likely be faster to resolve via an online meeting. Would you be able to meet for a quick Zoom call? If so, please DM me on Twitter: https://twitter.com/dmcghan